# Why isn't the undo variable updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code:

```js
import useUndo from 'use-undo';
export default function UndoTable(props){
    const [hightLightCellIndex, setHightLightCellIndex] = useState(-1);
    let [
        rosterList,
        undoUtil
    ]=useUndo(props.rosterTableData.rosterList);
        
    let activeShiftInfoList=props.rosterTableData.shiftInfoList;
    let calendarUtility=props.rosterTableData.calendarUtility;
    let monthlyCalendar=props.rosterTableData.monthlyCalendar;
    let contextValue={
        activeShiftInfoList,
        calendarUtility,
        hightLightCellIndex,
        monthlyCalendar,
        rosterList,
        setHightLightCellIndex,
        undoUtil
    };    
    console.log(Object.keys(props.rosterTableData.rosterList["ITO1_1999-01-01"].shiftList).length);
    console.log(Object.keys(rosterList.present["ITO1_1999-01-01"].shiftList).length);
    //console.log(contextValue);
    return (
        <table>              
        </table>
    )
}
```

I am using [`use-undo`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-undo) package to implement the undo feature.

I use the useUndo hook to convert the parent provided data (i.e. `props.rosterTableData.rosterList`) into the undo variable `rosterList`.

**The Problem:**

I found that the content of `rosterList` does not update when the content of `props.rosterTableData.rosterList` is updated.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to modify the code to the following:

```js
import useUndo from 'use-undo';
export default function UndoTable(props){
    const [hightLightCellIndex, setHightLightCellIndex] = useState(-1);
    let [
        rosterList,
        undoUtil
    ]=useUndo(props.rosterTableData.rosterList);
        
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(Object.keys(props.rosterTableData.rosterList["ITO1_1999-01-01"].shiftList).length);
        console.log(Object.keys(rosterList.present["ITO1_1999-01-01"].shiftList).length);
        },[props.rosterTableData])
    //console.log(contextValue);
        
    return (
        <table>              
        </table>
    )
}
```

Unfortunately, the problem still exists.
Is there any way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using `useUndo` incorrectly. See the [docs](https://github.com/homerchen19/use-undo#readme)

What you pass into the `useUndo` function is the `initialState`, so it will not update if you pass a different value. If you want to reset the undo state you should call the reset method:

```
useEffect(() => {
    undoUtil.reset(props.rosterTableData.rosterList)
}, [props.rosterTableData.rosterList])
```